# Select menu's hierarchy show

Tags: 7, routes

[image: Select menu]

I would like it to show the hierarchy of menu's links. Testimonials and Company are under About us. How can I achieve this effect? Let me specify with an image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the `About us` as `Expanded` and place the menu items `Testimonials`, `Company` under the About us. Please see the attached screenshots

[image]

[image]

Here, `About us` acts as parent item of `Testimonials` and `Company`.
After that just need to add and set the `css` in `style.css` file to the menu to be displayed accordingly.

Hope it works for you!